# Can mongodb's embedded documents be modeled in web2py DAL ?

Tags: mongodb, web2py, database

How can this mongodb embedded document structure be modeled in Web2PY DAL ?

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: 12345
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: 12345
                }
              ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mongodb, the web2py DAL can be like this

```
db = DAL('mongodb://username:password@localhost/test', pool_size=0)
db.define_table('address',
                Field('street'),
                Field('city'),
                Field('state'),
                Field('zip'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('table',
                Field('name'),
                Field('address','list:reference address'),
                format='%(name)s')
```

For insertion you can do

```
first = db.address.insert(street = '123 Fake Street',
                          city = 'Faketon',
                          state = 'MA',
                          zip = '12345')
second = db.address.insert(street = '1 Some Other Street',
                          city = 'Boston',
                          state = 'MA',
                          zip = '12345')
db.table.insert(name = 'Joe Bookreader', address = [first, second])
```

Or directly you can do this code:

```
db.define_table('table_name',Field('name'),Field('addresses','text'))
list_data =  [
            {
              street: "123 Fake Street",
              city: "Faketon",
              state: "MA",
              zip: 12345
            },
            {
              street: "1 Some Other Street",
              city: "Boston",
              state: "MA",
              zip: 12345
            }
          ]
db.table_name.insert(name='Joe Bookreader', addresses=list_data)
```

Comment: MongoDB works better without Web2pyDAL , its very easy. Only if you need cross platofrm db syntax u need DAL. Not sure how if auth works in web2py+mongo tho , haven't update for long.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `list` and 'json` types under the documentation section here:

http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Record-representation

Comment: I'm trying to model embedded documents. Wouldn't using a list and json data just add an array of text from the point of view of DAL? The embedded documents wouldn't be accessible as documents. Or would they?

Comment: The documentation you should be looking at should say <sic>".. added specifically for MongoDB .." meaning that the storage works differently to how it would appear in a standard RDBMS. That said, it's all experimental and subject to change.